# Facebook feeds on iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, json, feed

How can I display face book feeds related to a group on an iOS App?

Is there any JSON/JSONP call to fetch the feeds??

Any help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest - is just to show a web page on web view. Facebook manages itself to fit the width of your webView control.

```
// Load facebook data
NSString *fbUrlAddress = @"http://www.facebook.com/FLORtiles"; // here you put your own group
//Create a URL object.
NSURL *fbUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:fbUrlAddress];
NSString *webHTMLfb = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:fbUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
//NSLog(@"webHTML of facebook: %@", webHTMLfb);
//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *fbRequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fbUrl];
//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[fbWebView loadRequest:fbRequestObj];
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to get familiar with [Facebook's Graph Api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/)

Answer (score 0):

Go through this -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/