# how to display facebook news feeds in ios without Login?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I need to display facebook feeds in ios. For example I need to display the feeds of "https://www.facebook.com/Google" in a view.

I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599278/facebook-feeds-on-ios-app) but the solution here displays only the full page? Is there any other way to display the feeds alone? without asking for login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get feeds from a Facebook page, you can use [FacebookGraphAPI](https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/).
You don't need to LogIn to get the feeds, you can fetch the feeds from a page by using the url:

https://graph.facebook.com/Google/feed?access_token=YourAcessToken  .

Replace the 'YourAccessToken" with a real access token which you can get by registering your application at [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com).
This will return a JSON which you can parse and get the feeds.

Regards

**NB**:
Here, in this sample URL I had used "Google" as the facebook page name for your requirement, you can change it with the name of the page from which you need to get feeds.

Comment: Can you please provide some code snippet. It would be helpful as am new to FB sdk..

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I will give a try and getback to you... thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah I didnt try though. I got stuck up with some other work.

Comment: I will update you once I done with it. And for now I accepted as the answer.

Comment: We cant get access token without login to our account. So probably we wont be able to display news feeds without login.